# How to only get the first TD value with id Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a web app where I have a simple table.

On a specific action I call DoThis and pass the attribute of TR to this function.

The problem I have is, for **val2** - I can have multiple TD's with the same ID. All of the TDs with **id=valTwo** will have the same text() value.

If for example, I have the two TD's with **id=valTwo**, and each of the TD's text value  = TEST, then when I run through my code below, then **val2 = TESTTEST**.

In which case when I set val1.val(val2) then val1 = 'TESTTEST' - I just want it to simply be 'TEST'

```js
function DoThis(code) {
  val valCode = code
  var tr = $('tr[valCode=' + valCode + ']');
  var val1 = tr.find('td[id=valOne] input');
  var val2 = tr.find('td[id=valTwo]').text();
 
  val1.val(val2);         
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is, for this line:

```js
var val2 = tr.find('td[id=valTwo]').text();
```

I'm trying to only select the first or only 1 TD with **id=ValTwo**.

I have tried things like:

```js
var val2 = tr.find('td:first[id=valTwo]').text();
```

and

```js
var val2 = tr.find('td:eq(0)[id=valTwo]').text();
```

But I must be getting the syntax wrong. Any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: An ID has to be unique...

Comment: _"I can have multiple TD's with the same ID"_ -- this is a bad idea. [From MDN's `id` reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): _"The `id` global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which **must be unique in the whole document.**"_  Having multiple `id` with the same value in a document can lead to issues that are maddeningly difficult to debug.  I _strongly_ advise you to fix this before doing anything else.

Comment: `id` should be unique.  if you're using `class` then to select first `td` you have to change the syntax as `var val2 = $(tr.find('td. valTwo')[0]).text();` or simply you can do `$('.valTwo').eq(0).text()`

Comment: @Praveen - this does it. If you would like to post as answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```js
  function getFunction() {
            var table = $("#example tr");
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < table.length; i++) {
                arr.push((table[i].childNodes[1].innerText) + " </br>");
            }
            $("#result").html(arr)

        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="container">

    <table class="table" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>Handle</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>fat</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>twitter</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h4 id="result"></h4>
    <button onclick="getFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">GET</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```